# Define in Tomcat accessible directly from http://localhost

Tags: tomcat, https, webserver

I am able to get access to my application when typing `http://localhost:8080` in my web browser.  I would like to setup Tomcat 7 webserver in such a way that I only need to type `http://localhost` to get straight to the web app using port 8080.

How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

Set the Tomcat http connectors port to 80, or install an apache web server and redirect requests using mod_jk or mod_proxy.